# how do I train YOLOR with rotated bounding box?

Tags: yolov5

for YOLOR I am using this repo:

```
https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolor
```

While for labeling I am using label studio which gives the opportunity to rotate the bounding boxes to fit perfectly the object I want to use for training.

I am using rotated bounding boxes because I am working on aerial images and I want to get rid of the background.

When exporting images and labels in yolo format, the related file with coordinates loses the rotation angle.

Is there a way to keep this parameter in the exported file?
will YOLOR consider this parameter by default?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Oriented Object Detection to do this. Try it out.  https://github.com/hukaixuan19970627/yolov5_obb